# When does pageload fire?

Tags: jquery-mobile

If I change

```
$(document).on('pageshow',myFunction);
```

to

```
$(document).on('pageload',myFunction);
```

and refresh the page, the pageload function never fires.  What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pageload](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/) events are only triggered for pages that are AJAX-loaded from the network.

If you want your handler to be called for pages that are already embedded in your HTML document, you can bind to [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) instead:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", myFunction);
```